# Upgrading Android tablet with Bluetooth dongle Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a question regarding Bluetooth-coding on an Android tablet. This tablet is running Android 4.2 and does not have native Bluetooth support. So logically on the following code-snippet, it will go to in the if clause:

```
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (btAdapter == null) {
    // No Bluetooth
}
else {
    // Bluetooth available
}
```

Now is it somehow possible to "upgrade" the tablet, that it will go on the else-clause? The idea is, to buy an Android compatible USB-Dongle (e.g. [This one](https://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/bled112-bluetooth-smart-dongle/)), and than use the Androids native API for bluetooth development.

Root is available, so if I need to make changes to some system-configs, that should not be a problem. So how can I use the Androids built-in Bluetooth API with a USB Dongle?

Comment: which dongle are you thinking to use if they both conform to some protocol then yes.but USB dongles i have programmed with some are generally serial port emulation over USB.i dont think android bluetooth API is designed this way. when the chip is inside your phone then it may be some other protocol like simple UART or i2c.still i am not saying it is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in contact with the manufacturer of the device. The Research and Development Team there told me, that there is absolutely no way, to get Bluetooth running on this device.

So for me the answer is: No, it's impossible to upgrade Bluetooth for this device.